# Disabling perticualar value of second dropdown when same value from first dropdown is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Disabling perticualar value of second dropdown when same value from first dropdown is chosen.Here's  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/59/)! is the given link
in which i have to perform particular opration here below is my code which is code for calling data..

```
 Here is My Html
```

```html
<select name="select-choice-1" class="filter-menu" id="dropDownFromCity">
                            <option value="">- -Select From City- -</option>
                        </select>
                      
                       
                        <select name="select-choice-1" class="filter-menu" id="dropDownToCity"   >
                            <option value="">- -Select To City- -</option>
                        </select>
                     
                       
                        <select name="select-choice-1" class="filter-menu" id="dropDownViaCity"  multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-placeholder="false" >
                             <option value="">- -Select Via Via- -</option>
                        </select>
```

Here is my jquery which call dropdown data

```html
        function selectRadioButton() {
            var airPortId = $('input[name=airPortName]:checked').val();
            var loadingbar = $("#loadingBar");
            loadingbar.empty().append(window.loadingAnimation);
    
            setTimeout(function () {
                var Surl = "http://PassengerService.asmx/LoadDropDownlist";
                var dataString = "{'i':'" + airPortId + "'}";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: Surl,
                    corssDomain: true,
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var jdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        $("#dropDownFromCity").html("");
                        $("#dropDownToCity").html("");
                        $("#dropDownViaCity").html("");
                        //$("#dropdownViaCitySecond").html("");
                        $("#loadingBar").html("");
                        
                        $("#dropDownFromCity").append($("<option></option>").val("").html("- -Select From City- -"));
                        $("#dropDownToCity").append($("<option></option>").val("").html("- -Select To City- -"));
                        $("#dropDownViaCity").append($("<option></option>").val("").html("- -Select Via City- -"));
                        //$("#dropdownViaCitySecond").append($("<option></option>").val("").html("- -Select Via City- -"));
                        $.each(jdata, function (key, value) {
    
                            $("#dropDownFromCity").append($("<option></option>").val(value.AirportDetailsId).html(value.LocationDetail));
                            $("#dropDownToCity").append($("<option></option>").val(value.AirportDetailsId).html(value.LocationDetail));
                            $("#dropDownViaCity").append($("<option></option>").val(value.AirportDetailsId).html(value.LocationDetail));
                             
                            //$("#dropdownViaCitySecond").append($("<option></option>").val(value.AirportDetailsId).html(value.LocationDetail))
                        });
                        $("#dropDownViaCity").selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh');
                        
                        $("#dropDownFromCity-button").find('span').html("- -Select From City- -");
                        $("#dropDownToCity-button").find('span').html("- -Select To City- -");
                        $("#dropDownViaCity-button").find('span').html("- -Select Via City- -");
                        //$("#dropdownViaCitySecond-button").find('span').html("- -Select Via City- -");
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
    
        }
```

Here is my validation on dropdown class

```html
 $('.filter-menu').on('change', function () {
            $('.filter-menu').find('option').prop('disabled', false);
    
            $('.filter-menu').each(function () {
                $('.filter-menu').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            });
    
            // rebuild select menus
            $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        });
```

Comment: You only have one dropdown in your jsfiddle...

Comment: That was just for an idea how to create multiple selection dropdown..because third dropdown is my multiple selection dropdown

Comment: So you expect someone to show you how to disable a second dropdown when one is being used but in your example source code you only display one....?

Comment: I think it would be relevant for you to display multiple dropdowns since you expect someone to explain how to disable at least one of them while the other is in use otherwise people will have nothing to work with. You shouldn't expect others to do more work than is required to solve your issue. Please take the time to update your example source code and I'm sure someone will then be willing to help you. Also please display your attempt(s) and explain what problems you have encountered. Thank you.

Comment: #NewToJS can u please check my updated code..and also attached jsfiddle demo